# jQuery replace string in matched string

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I want to replace the text which is inside the brackets matched by regex (The first group of regex)

In other words i try to catch a string like "[SomeText][1]" and replace the number 1 with number 2 in it. The code below is replacing all the string with 2 which i dont want.

```
regex = new RegExp("\\[.*\\]\\[(1)\\]");
textarea.val().replace(regex, 2);
```

SomeText is changing. So `replace("[SomeText][1]", "[SomeText][2]")` does not work.

Comment: Why not just `textarea.val().replace(/\[1\]$/, '[2]');`?

Comment: There can be multiple [1] but not multiple [SomeText][1]

Comment: It only replace the last `[1]` since there is a `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace method in JavaScript allows you to reference any captured match in the string (captured with parens). You reference these as $1 for the first, $2 for the second, etc. up to $9. You can change it to something like the following and I believe you'll get what you want:

```
regex = new RegExp("(\\[.*\\]\\[)1(\\])");
textarea.val().replace(regex, "$12$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you literally always want to replace the `1` with `2`, then:

```
var str = "[SomeText][1]";
str = str.replace(/(\[[^\]]+\])(\[1\])/g, "$1[2]");
console.log(str); // "[SomeText][2]"
```

Note the use of `$1` to repeat the leading bit. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/pociko/1/)

But the more interesting problem would be *adding one* to the number in the second brackets, which can be done by giving `replace` a function to call: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/pociko/2/)

```
var str = "[SomeText][2]";
str = str.replace(/(\[[^\]]+\])\[(\d+)\]/g, function(m, c1, c2) {
    return c1 + "[" + String(+c2 + 1) + "]";
});
console.log(str); // "[SomeText][3]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep there must be some super smarty pants way to do this but here's a simple suggestion:

```
var bracketIdx = textarea.val().indexOf("[1]");
var value = textarea.val();
value[bracketIdx+1] = 2;
textarea.val() = value;
```

...sounds like you're doing something a little strange though would be happy to explain a better way if you illustrated what you want to accomplish in a little more detail. I only ask because the little snippet I wrote is a little ugly.